# How do you set FileFilter when using FileReference.download()?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using `FileReference` to retrieve an exported CSV file from the server. The `fileReference.download(url, "myFilename.csv")` method call seems to be working and I can download the file.

The only problem with this is that I can't seem to be able to set the file filter. In my save dialog, the file type filter is always `*.*`, which is really bad. The user trying to save the file has to manually type in the .csv extension. How do I change the filter of the dialog box to only show `*.csv` and not `*.*`?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the lines where you are decalring file filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the answer is "No way to do it." as of Flex 3.5. Oh well.